# Using math commands inside \ExplSyntaxOn

Tags: math-operators, latex3, xparse

I am trying to define new commands using `xparse` package. To be specific I am trying to abbreviate integrals from this `\int\limits_{a}^{b}\ f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x` to a more reader friendly `\dint[a,b]{f(x)}{x}`.

I have the code inside `\ExplSyntax` so that I can use `\use_i` to access the elements of my first arg `[a,b]` which `\SplitArgument` split into a list. The Problem I am facing now is that `\use_i` does not seem to work inside `\limits`; the code runs fine not using `\limits` so my implementation of `\use_i` should be ok and the code also runs if I omit `\use_i` and therefore the `\Explsyntax` env and just use two different enclosed arguments instead of a combined one.

The code I am currently using:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xparse}

% Version 1, preferred but does not work
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\dint}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}r[] m m}{%
    \int\limits_{\use_i:nn#1}^{\use_ii:nn#1}\ #2\ \mathrm{d}#3%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Version 2, does run but is just to narrow down the error
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\dintt}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}r[] m m}{%
    \int \use_i:nn#1^{\use_ii:nn#1}\ #2\ \mathrm{d}#3%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% Version 3, works but 
\NewDocumentCommand{\dinttt}{r[] r[] m m}{%
    \int\limits_{#1}^{#2}\ #3\ \mathrm{d}#4%
}

\begin{document}
%    Example 1: \( \dint[a,b]{f(x)}{x} \) % Fails with error
    
    Example 2: \( \dintt[a,b]{f(x)}{x} \) % works, but is just for testing
    
    Example 3: \( \dinttt[a][b]{f(x)}{x} \) % Works, but slightly annoying
\end{document}
```

Could it be that this is because functions are handled differently inside a `Latex3` env? This is my first time dabbling with `Latex3` Syntax so bear with me ;)

Comment: `_` is a letter in expl3, so you can't use it to create a subscript. Use `\int\limits \c_math_subscript_token {\use_i:nn#1}...`

Comment: After `\ExplSyntaxOn` `_` is a letter, not a math subscript. You can replace ist with `\sb`. Or not use expl-Syntax but (surrounded by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` instead) use `\int\limits_{\@firstoftwo#1}^{\@secondoftwo#1}`

Comment: Ahh I see thanks for pointing that out! Substituing `_` with `\sb` works perfectly. Can't use `\makeatletter` unfortunately because my `\tcolorbox` env does not like it (errors out)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is just with `\limits_` in the first code, because `_` is not the subscript character.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\dint}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}r[] m m}
  {
    \int
    \limits
    \c_math_subscript_token   { \use_i:nn  #1 }
    \c_math_superscript_token { \use_ii:nn #1 }
    #2
    \,
    \mathrm{d}#3
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

The two `\`  commands are wrong: the first one produces too much space between the integral and the function, the second one too much space between the function and the differential.

Compare in the following picture: top is your version, bottom is mine.

[image]

Full example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\dint}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}r[] m m}
  {
    \int
    \limits
    \c_math_subscript_token   { \use_i:nn  #1 }
    \c_math_superscript_token { \use_ii:nn #1 }
    #2
    \,
    \mathrm{d}#3
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
& \int\limits_{a}^b \ f(x)\ \mathrm{d}x \\
& \int\limits_{a}^b f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x \\
& \dint[a,b]{f(x)}{x}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: I left the dreaded `\mathrm{d}` even if I'm against it.